# How to pass variables to an Ember app?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ember.js, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to connect an Ember app to a REST API generated by WordPress. The API requires a nonce value passed along in the header with the request to help prevent CSRF attacks. The nonce value is usually provided in a global javascript variable before the app is loaded. (The process is described well in the [REST API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/#cookie-authentication)) This works fine with the default REST API client that is shipped with the WordPress plugin, for example (written with Backbone).

I'm loading Ember from a PHP template and using a WordPress function to generate the root API URL and nonce. The JavaScript object looks something like this:

```
var wpApiSettings = {"root":"http:\/\/apisite.dev\/wp-json\/","versionString":"wp\/v2\/","nonce":"3d00cd1c5c"};
```

The question is, how to I get that nonce into Ember so I can make an authenticated API request?

Comment: I guess wpApiSettings would be in javascript global scope so you can easily access it like wpApiSettings.nonce anywhere in ember app.

Comment: No, to my knowledge that's not the case with Ember, items in the global scope are not automatically available within the app.

Comment: yes you are right. can you try setting wpApiSettings in  window.wpApiSettings in app.js or in index.html,  Is that possible?. if it is, then you can access it in your emberjs code anywhere like window.wpApiSettings.nonce.

Comment: there should be a meta tag named `<your-app-name>/config/environment`. Maybe you can modify it. It is an escaped JSON string .

Comment: @ykaragol Thanks, that's a good hint. Instead of trying to edit the environment option, I created some additional meta tags with the values that I needed. Then I can retrieve them from within my adapter. I need to learn how to properly use Ember initializers, and I will post a solution here.